# Calculating rectangle having 2 coordinates and 1 length

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, polygons, rectangles

How could I calculate the other 2 points if I have a rectangle with 2 points and 1 length given?

[image]

```
A = 50.88259382849774,6.003988087177277
B = 50.88269282423443,6.0036662220954895
C = ?
D = ?

AB = 25m

All sides are 90 degrees
```

PS: I already asked this question but in triangle form so I thought maybe this way it would be possible to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. By Thales' theorem, if $O$ denotes the midpoint of $AB$ and $r$ is half the length of $AB$ then *every* pair of diametrically opposite points on the circle of radius $r$ with center $O$ completes the rectangle.

Comment: But it must be possible if I know that all sides are 90 degrees right? I see this website doing it : http://www.mathopenref.com/coordrectangle.html

Comment: That website has $AB$ as an edge, not a diagonal, of the rectangle. You can complete the rectangle if you know two adjacent corners and the length of the diagonal. In your case, not even the length of another side would help; there would still be two possibilities for the locations of the remaining corners.

Comment: @SinanSamet: That web site marks *edge* lengths, which adds information to the problem. You have the length of the *diagonal*, which is already known from the coordinates of the pair of opposite corners, so it adds *no* information. You might as well omit that length, which indicates that you don't have enough information. That's because your problem has five degrees of freedom, essentially width and height of the rectangle, rotation and position in two directions. Knowing two corners, you know four relevant real numbers, but you still need one which is independent from what you know.

Comment: Ah okay I guess I have to find another way then.. I am trying to simulate the 90 degrees function of http://www.google.com/mapmaker you can see it when you press Add new -> Add building outlines -> Any building and hold shift when you draw a polygon. (just in case someone was interested to know)